# Notifications from different project triggered in an app

Tags: android, notifications

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` to notify me when I plug the charger on/off.
I set a `notifications` to inform me about it, but I'm also getting notifications from *second project* (does the same) about charger plugged on/off.

How is this even possible? I even deleted the project from Eclipse, I have no code and the notifications still pop up. How can I prevent it? I did `build` a project, didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall the app from the device.  On my phone its menu manage apps / select the app / delete.

Comment: I had to uninstall the second app from which the notifications came from, but it worked, thanks!